# Plivo "Bad Media Description Error"

Tags: webrtc, voip, plivo

I'm using Plivo WebRTC to make and received VoIP calls. Sometimes when I use Plivo.conn.call from JS SDK to start a call a get "Bad Media Description" error. This happens once every five to ten calls. Does anybody knows what "Bad Media Description" error means? Has anyone had this problem?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you are using, including the line that's throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could have looked into the Plivo JS Library using the Chrome console debug with break points. This way you could have identified the issue yourself.

It seems that this error occurs when the received response does not include the SDP (answer body) which is translated into a 400 type error or when something goes wrong when creating the answer (perhaps setRemoteDescription), which is very generic and translated into a 488 type error.

You should put more logs and steps if you want to receive any help, but other than that, there is not enough information to go on...

Comment: Do you have the Plivo JS Library not min I could not found it?  If not, do you know where I can found it? (I only have the min version) The Plivo support team told that the only way that they could share this file, is with a legal agreement. This is the only way I could add more logs.